# changing background colour for current day php css

Tags: php, html, css

[here is the screenshoot of my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4aF5.png)
I am trying to make a calander have some problem with the code.The code where error is generatring is  tablerow.php according to me I have put comment where I think the error is.
I am trying to change the current day background colour but instead of changing the colour of specific cell the whole month background colour is changed so for whole month of February the colour is green.

calander.php

```
<html>
<?php include 'dbconnect.php' ?>

<head>Event Calander</head>
<body>
<script>
        function goLastMonth(month, year){
            if(month == 1) {
                --year;
                month = 13;
            }
            document.location.href ="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?month="+(month-1)+"&year="+year;

        }
        function goNextMonth(month, year){
            if(month == 12) {
                ++year;
                month = 0;
            }
            document.location.href ="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?month="+(month+1)+"&year="+year;

        }
</script>
<style>
        .today{
            background-color: #00ff00;
        }
        .event{
            background-color: #FF8080;
        }
</style>

<table border='0'>
<tr>

    <td width='50px' colspan='7' align="center">
    <?php include 'tableheader.php' ?>
    <?php include 'addingData.php' ?>
    <?php echo $monthName.", ".$year; ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td width='50px'>Sun</td>
    <td width='50px'>Mon</td>
    <td width='50px'>Tue</td>
    <td width='50px'>Wed</td>
    <td width='50px'>Thu</td>
    <td width='50px'>Fri</td>
    <td width='50px'>Sat</td>
</tr>
    <?php include 'tablerow.php' ?>

</table>
<table >
        <tr>
            <td ><input style='width:50px;' type='button' value='<'name='previousbutton' onclick ="goLastMonth(<?php echo $month.",".$year?>)"></td>
            <td width='50px'></td>
            <td width='50px'></td>
            <td width='50px'></td>
            <td width='50px'></td>
            <td width='50px'></td>
            <td width='50px'><input style='width:50px;' type='button' value='>'name='nextbutton' onclick ="goNextMonth(<?php echo $month.",".$year?>)"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
<?php include 'schedule.php' ?>
</body>
</html>
```

tablerow.php(this where i change the colour for the current day)

```
<?php
        echo "<tr>";

        $first_day = mktime(0,0,0,$month, 1, $year) ;
        $name_of_day = date('w', $first_day) ; //get the day of the weeek
        //caluting blank days for the month for diaplay 
        switch($name_of_day){   
            case "0": $blank = 0; 
            break;   
            case "1": $blank = 1; 
            break;   
            case "2": $blank = 2; 
            break;   
            case "3": $blank = 3; 
            break;   
            case "4": $blank = 4; 
            break;   
            case "5": $blank = 5; 
            break;   
            case "6": $blank = 6; 
            break;   
        }

        $total_days = cal_days_in_month(0, $month, $year) ;  
        $day_count = 1; 
        while ( $blank > 0 )   {   
            echo "<td></td>";   
            $blank = $blank-1;   
            $day_count++;  
        }
        $day_num = 1;
        while ( $day_num <= $total_days )   
        {  
            $todaysDate = date("n/j/Y");
            $dateToCompare = $month. '/' . $day. '/' . $year;
            echo "<td align='center' ";
            //this is where i am comparing two dates but it is giving error
            //every day of the current month is turnin green
            if ($todaysDate == $dateToCompare)
            {
                echo "class ='today'";

            }  
            echo "> <a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?month=".$month."&day=".$day_num."&year=".$year."&v=true'>".$day_num."</a></td>";

            $day_num++;   
            $day_count++;    
            //Make sure we start a new row every week  
            if ($day_count > 7)  
            {  
                echo "</tr><tr>";  
                $day_count = 1;  
            }  
        }
        while ( $day_count >1 && $day_count <=7 )   
            {   
                echo "<td> </td>";   
                $day_count++;   
            }  


            echo "</tr>"


?>
```

Comment: Is it adding the class to each `td` in the month or is just all green without the class being added?

Comment: it is adding the class to every td i have upload screenshot of my result

Comment: You don't change `$month`. `$day` and `$year` in the `while` loop, should this date change somehow?

Comment: i tried to echo both the $todaydate and $dateToCompare both of them have the same date in them 2/7/2016

Comment: I know, so shouldn't you compute `$dateToCompare` based on the `$day_count` variable? You can use `mktime()` for that

Comment: @AlonEitan thank you it solved my error i just changed my  $day to $day_num which i am increasing every time i am in loop so dumb of me

Comment: @Android2841 It's quite alright :) We can all make mistakes like that

Comment: Oh, I didn't see your comments and answered the question, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
$dateToCompare = $month. '/' . $day. '/' . $year;
```

into this:

```
$dateToCompare = $month. '/' . $day_num. '/' . $year;
```